# How to integrate spreadsheet/excel kind of view to my application using python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create an application using python, In which I would like to able to read a .csv or .xlsx file and display its contents on my application, I believe there should be some packages which helps to do this in python, can I have some suggestions?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

I think working with PyQt for large application is the best option ( for large applications ) but tkinter is the secondary option for fast small apps.

Answer (score 1):

Reading CSV and Excel files is simple with pandas.

With these functions, you create a Pandas DataFrame out of the content of the Files. You need du `import pandas as pd`. If you don't have pandas installed you can install it with the command line command `pip install pandas`. If you are not familiar with pandas you can transform it into a numpy 2-Dimensional list if you use die `.values()` function on the DataFrame. To get a standard Python list you apply the list function to the numpy array.

```
df_csv = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

[Pandas Dos - Read CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

```
df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)
```

[Pandas Docs - Read Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

If you want to work with a normal list:

```
import pandas as pd
data = list(pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=100).to_numpy())
```

I don´t know a good package for user interfaces. Normally I create an web-interface with JavaScript hosted by Flask.